# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated to Android Studio 1.2 and now have a two errors.

When I first open my project I get this error at the top of the screen.

"Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly."

[image]

In the Messages Gradle Sync I get

[image]

My gradle files are:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
        {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'ScoularAndroidKey'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/bschmiedeler/.AndroidStudio/scoularkeystore.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }
    name="Scoular"
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.scoular.scoular"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug{
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile files('src/main/assets/library-1.0.10.jar')
}
```

By looking through Stack Overflow I have found some potential solutions.

I have tried File ==> Invalidate and Restart and removing the files that you are supposed to. I am just stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: I am using gradle version 2.2.1. I tried changing the version number in the class path to 2.2.1 but still get this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug with Android Studio 1.2:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160899

The main solution is to wait for their fix.

I have had luck re-importing the project, but I have to do it every time I open the project.

Comment: Kio, wow, that is bad news. This is a pretty major bug. I will check out the link to see if I can over come it until a fix is released. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I was very sad myself.  I've been following the bug and the good news is that there seems to be a lot of activity on it, and the team is prioritizing it. You're welcome!